# Get data from json pages using services with same controller in different partial pages

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-services, angular-controller, angular-factory

Am trying to get different json pages data using services within the same controller. Here is the sample code

app.js file

`var app = angular.module('drinks-app', ['ui.bootstrap']);`

//Setting up the app

`app.config([ '$routeProvider', function( $routeProvider ) {`

// routes

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
   templateUrl: 'drinks_list.html',
   controller: 'MainCtrl'
}).when('/:drinkid', {
   templateUrl: 'drink_editor.html',
   controller: 'MainCtrl'
}).otherwise({
   redirectTo: '/drinks', 
   templateUrl: 'drinks_list.html',
   controller: 'MainCtrl'
});
```

// controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function( $scope, $location, $routeParams, Drink) {
   Drink.getDrinks().success(function(drink) {       
        $scope.data = drink   
   });
});
```

//factory

```
app.factory('Drink', function($http) {
    var Drink = function(data) { angular.extend(this, data);    
        this.getData = function() {
             return $http.get('drink.json').then(function(response){
                    return response.data; 
             });
         }      
     }
})
```

Comment: Any errors? The code works? You need to provide more info